# Apache Flink: My application does not resume from a checkpoint when I restart it

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink job in which I am reading files from a folder and dumping it in database. New files will come in that folder daily.

I have enabled checkpointing so that if for any reason Flink job stops and I need to restart, Flink job should not read the files that already been read.

I have added below lines in my code but when I restart my job, Flink job again reads all the files.

```java
env.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend("file:///C://Users//folder"));
env.enableCheckpointing(10L);
```

Answer (score 10):

Checkpoints are a mechanism to recover from failures during the execution of an application, not to resume an application that was explicitly canceled.

If you have a running application and the execution fails (for whatever reason), Flink will try to recover the application by restarting it and initializing the state of the operators from the last checkpoint. If the recovery fails (for example because not enough processing slots are available), the job is considered as failed.

If you manually cancel an application and restart it, Flink will not a checkpoint to initialize the state of the operators. In fact, Flink will (by default) delete all checkpoints when you cancel an application.

The concept you are looking for are savepoints. Savepoints are very similar to checkpoints but manually triggered by the user and not automatically deleted when the application is explicitly canceled. When starting an application, you can start it from a savepoint which means that the operator state is initialized from the savepoint.

There are also different restart strategies available to configure how often and in which intervals Flink tries to restart a failed application.

Comment: Could you please help me in configuring Savepoints for my scenario.

Comment: There is nothing to configure if your application has checkpointing enabled. You can trigger savepoints from the CLI client or the REST API.

Comment: You can kill the task manager process. The job won't recover until the JM has enough processing slots to restart the job. You either need a standby TM process or have to manually start a new one.

Comment: @FabianHueske In my situation, a job is running and then I restart it with Intellij's IDEA rerun configuration button. The message I'm getting is 'Process finished with exit code 130(interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT'. After it runs again, should it restart from the last checkpoint or create a new one?

Answer (score 4):

@fabian-hueske covered all aspects of whats going on with your "planned" restart

You should plan to cancel the job with a savepoint

```
flink cancel --withSavepoint ${SAVEPOINT_DIR} ${JOBID}
```

Restart the new Job with the savepoint from prev step..

```
flink run -s ${SAVE_POINT} -p ${PARALLELISM} -d ${JOB_JAR} ${JOB_ARGS}
```

Comment: flink cancel -s ${SAVEPOINT_DIR} ${JOBID}

Comment: @user544192 As of version 1.9, use flink stop [-p targetDirectory] [-d] <jobID>